# How to add url/link on d3 objects in Cal-heatmap

Tags: d3.js, cal-heatmap

As a newbie to both d3 and js, or just front-end in general, I have spent enough time to basically understand how [Cal-heatmap](http://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/v2/) works. I have a working version, but really want to make the tiny boxes on the calendar hyperlinks for extra functionality, and reading the source code was a complete disaster for me. I suppose I should add `.attr("xlink:href", url)` to some object as suggested [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8150631), but I really can't figure out where. Is there anyone that has done something similar? Also I don't really understand how attributes I specify when initializing is passed through to the source code either. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes a little bit of hackery.

After the heatmap draws you could:

```
d3.selectAll('.graph-rect')
  .each(function(d){
    var a = d3.select( this.parentNode ) // get the parent of the rect (it's a g)
      .append("a") // append the link
      .attr("xlink:href","http://www.google.com")
      .attr("target", "_blank"); // set its link
    var rect = this;
    rect.remove(); // remove the rect
    a.insert(function(){return rect}); // and re-add it to the link
  });
```

Working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/JWPbDt2ER9LCFBzaSK6V?p=preview).

Comment: Hi, I'm just curious: why do you use a function argument for `insert`?

Comment: @CoolBlue, from the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#insert): `The name may be specified either as a constant string or as a function that returns the DOM element to append.`

Comment: Ok, I could have sworn I've used bare DOM references in that context before but apparently not coz, yeh... It fails. There you go.

Comment: Hey @Mark, turned out there was a `ClickOn` functionality provided.. but this definitely provides more insight. Anyways thanks!

Comment: @MegaMax, Do'h, assumed you knew the ease of an `click` handler; would have made this answer so much easier :) Good luck with your future `d3`ing!